# Error in Bash shell when running Pulp on vast.ai cloud

Tags: python, pulp

I'm running my python program with Pulp library on vast.ai cloud, where I have to use Bash shell. I've installed python3 and Pulp with the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository universe
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

```
$ sudo pip install pulp
$ sudo apt-get install glpk-utils
$ sudo apt-get install coinor-cbc
```

Now, when the values `n` and `m` which determine the size of a problem are quite small (`n` < 25), everything is ok and the program returns both the solution or status -1 (if there is no solution). But for the larger values  (`n` > 30), the following error message appears after the program has been executed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 58, in <module>
    Problem.solve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pulp/pulp.py", line 1913, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pulp/apis/coin_api.py", line 137, in actualSolve
    return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pulp/apis/coin_api.py", line 208, in solve_CBC
    + self.path
pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while trying to execute, use msg=True for more details/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc
```

I'll be very glad if you help me fix this error. Here's the main code:

```
from pulp import LpVariable, LpInteger, LpProblem, LpMaximize, lpSum

n = int(input())
m = int(input())
r = 3 * m - 2

# Vertices

Triple = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            Triple.append((i,j,k))

# Variables

Variable = LpVariable.dicts("Variables",[triple for triple in Triple],0,1,LpInteger)

# Objective

Problem = LpProblem("Problem",LpMaximize)
Problem += Variable[(0,0,0)]

# Constraints

# 1

Exclusion = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n - 1):
            for l in range(k + 1,n):
                Exclusion.append(((i,j,k),(i,j,l)))
                Exclusion.append(((i,k,j),(i,l,j)))
                Exclusion.append(((k,i,j),(l,i,j)))

for exclusion in Exclusion:
    s = exclusion[0]
    t = exclusion[1]
    Problem += Variable[s] + Variable[t] <= 1

# 2

for i in range(n):
    Problem += lpSum([Variable[(i,j,k)]] for j in range(n) for k in range(n)) == m
    Problem += lpSum([Variable[(j,i,k)]] for j in range(n) for k in range(n)) == m
    Problem += lpSum([Variable[(j,k,i)]] for j in range(n) for k in range(n)) == m

# 3

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            Ones = [triple for triple in Triple if triple[0] == i or triple[1] == j or triple[2] == k]
            Problem += lpSum([Variable[(triple)]] for triple in Ones) >= r
    
# Result

Problem.solve()

s = Problem.status

if s == 1:
    
    Triangle = []
    for triple in Triple:
        if Variable[triple].value() == 1:
            Triangle.append(triple)
            
    print(Triangle)

else:
    
    print(s)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with a shell.

Comment: this is just a guess, but if all runs good when small, but crashes at some threshold, perhaps you are running out of allocated memory?  if n~30, your constraint #4 is making roughly 30**4 or around 800,000 constraints.  Perhaps the `vast.ai` isn't so vast?

Comment: I see part of the Traceback, but I don't see any concrete error message in your question. A traceback is usually generated by an exception, so there should also be an exception message.

Comment: @user1934428 it's a bit left "Error while trying to execute, use msg=True for more details/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc"

Comment: This looks too general to me for a real error message. Did you try to use `msg=True`?

Comment: @user1934428 lol, I've tried to write it as a command in bash but it didn't work. So I have to put it in my code and wait bt 1 day of the execution. Also, I've read here that trying to use this with pulp in similar cases didn't give any specific information.

Comment: @Shawn  I'm just running a py file uploaded on their server using the default shell window :)

Comment: @AirSquid btw, in general, I'd recommend the machines they offer

Comment: I don't see how this related to bash. I don't know _pulp_, but my intuitive understanding of the message you got, is that you have to set `msg` to `True` when you are executing `solve()`. BTW, a commend like "I've tried to write it ..." is not really helpful, unless you update your question and show exactly how you tried it.

Comment: @user1934428 hey, you're absolutely right! I have set `msg` to `True` in `solve()`. Now, waiting for the result to add it to my question. BT how I write it, even Google translate can't help with my bad English (though, think it wasn't your point) :-)